# Asymptotes of $\Gamma(\frac{1}{2} +ix)$ when $\vert x \vert \to \infty$

Tags: asymptotics, gamma-function

I am currently looking for finding behaviour of the function $\vert \Gamma(\frac{1}{2}+ix) \vert$ when $x$ tends to $\infty$.
I think I need to use the Stirling's approximation but I don't see how.

Could anyone please help me?

Comment: See [A & S $(6.1.17)$ and $(6.1.30)$](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_256.htm) .

Comment: It tends exponentially to $0$. By plotting $|\Gamma(\tfrac12+ix)|$ with *Mathematica*, the graphic looks like a bell-shaped curve, with its maximum in $x=0$. The function is even, i.e., symmetrical with regards to the vertical axis Oy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with the [reflection formula $(6.1.17)$ from A&S](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_256.htm) :
$$\tag{1}\Gamma(z)\,\Gamma(1-z)=\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi\,z)}$$
and set $\,z:=\dfrac 12+ix\;$ then :
$$\tag{2}\Gamma\left(\frac 12+ix\right)\,\Gamma\left(\frac 12-ix\right)=\frac{\pi}{\sin\left(\frac {\pi}2+\pi ix\right)}=\frac{\pi}{\cos\left(-\pi ix\right)}$$
But $\;\displaystyle\Gamma(\overline{z})=\overline{\Gamma(z)}\;$ $(6.1.23)$  and $\;\cos(iy)=\cosh(y)\;$ so that $(2)$ becomes $(6.1.30)$ :
$$\tag{3}\Gamma\left(\frac 12+ix\right)\,\overline{\Gamma\left(\frac 12+ix\right)}=\left|\Gamma\left(\frac 12+ix\right)\right|^2=\frac{\pi}{\cosh\left(\pi x\right)}$$
The square root of the right term is the exact answer to your question for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @user130217: you are welcome!