# Estimate product of Gamma functions

Tags: real-analysis, special-functions, gamma-function, estimation

Consider the following expression

$$\left|\frac{\Gamma(q+1/2 + ix)\Gamma(q+1/2 - ix) }{\Gamma(1/2-q)^2}   \right|$$ with $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $q>\frac{1}{2}$.

I would like to know how this expression behaves for $x\rightarrow \infty$, respectively for $q\rightarrow \infty$. For this purpose I am wondering if it is possible to estimate the expression by elementary functions? For example for $q=0$ we would have an upper bound by $\frac{1}{\pi\cosh(\pi x)}$. Is there a similar estimate when $q>\frac{1}{2}$?

Comment: Perhaps this will help you: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Euler.27s_definition_as_an_infinite_product

Comment: Concerning $x\to\infty$ this [thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1882175/asymptotics-of-the-gamma-function-and-remainder/1882189#1882189) may help.

Answer (score 0):

Asymptotics expressions for $\Gamma$ were proposed in this [thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1882175/asymptotics-of-the-gamma-function-and-remainder/1882189#1882189) :
\begin{align}
|\Gamma(x+iy)|&\sim \sqrt{2\pi}\,\exp\left[\frac{\left(x-\frac 12\right)\;\ln\bigl(x^2+y^2\bigr)}2-y\;\arg(x+iy)-x+\sum\limits_{m=1}^\infty \frac{B_{2m}\;\Re\;{z^{1-2m}}}{2m\,(2m-1)}\right]\\
(1)\qquad&\sim \sqrt{2\pi}\,\bigl(x^2+y^2\bigr)^{\frac x2-\frac 14}\exp\left[-x-y\,\arg(x+iy)+\frac 1{12}\frac x{x^2+y^2}-\frac 1{360}\frac{x^3-3xy^2}{(x^2+y^2)^3}+\cdots\right]\\
\end{align}

(see too the end of this more detailed [exposition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/455306/real-and-imaginary-part-of-gamma-function))

Replacing your $\,q+1/2\,$ by $x$ and your $x$ by $y$ you want the asymptotics of :
$$\tag{2}\left|\frac{\Gamma(x + iy)}{\Gamma(1-x)}\right|^2=\left|\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{\pi}\right|^2\left|\Gamma(x)\,\Gamma(x + iy)\right|^2$$
where I used the [reflection formula $(6.1.17)$ from A&S](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_256.htm) : $\;\displaystyle\Gamma(x)\,\Gamma(1-x)=\frac{\pi}{\sin(\pi x)}\,$ .

Squaring $(1)$ twice (setting $y=0\,$ for $\Gamma(x)$ or using [Stirling's formula](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_257.htm)) should give you the wished asymptotic expressions.

Visual representation of the logarithm of your function :
[image: Visual ln]